# 500 error on google console when trying to access API

Tags: google-app-engine, console, google-api

Procedure:

- Go into the new console: console.developers.google.com
- Click on APIs

In the console I get the following code

```
GET https://console.developers.google.com/m/project/myappID/api 500 (Internal Server Error)
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:79(anonymous function)
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:79u
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:74f
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:72B
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:101B
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:101(anonymous function)
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:103g.$eval
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:113g.$digest
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:110g.$apply
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:114k
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:73B
third_party/javascript/angular/v1_2/angular.min.js:78v.onreadystatechange
```

This happens for all my apps.

Comment: Odd, I just tried and it worked for me. Try in an incognito window. Is there another account you can try and access from?

Comment: I tried with two different accounts, and it didnt work.

Comment: I tried. It worked for me too. Check now please, if it works.

Comment: Oh! Now it works. Don't know what it was. THanks :)